# Possible to have multiple content scripts for different functions?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am new to this, but I am trying to create a chrome extension to manipulate DOMs on the webpage. Currently, I have two buttons and each button will do different tasks. Does the following make sense? Also if I have multiple content scripts, how can I add them both into the manifest.json

popup.js:

```
function injectTheScript() {
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        // query the active tab, which will be only one tab
        //and inject the script in it
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "content_script.js"});
    });
}
function injectTheScript1() {
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        // query the active tab, which will be only one tab
        //and inject the script in it
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "content_script1.js"});
    });
}

document.getElementById('clickactivity').addEventListener('click', injectTheScript);
document.getElementById('clickactivity1').addEventListener('click', injectTheScript1);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with how you are injecting one content script per function. You could, however, make it a little simpler by not using `tabs.query()` to obtain the active tab.  The default tab used for [`tabs.executeScript()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) is the currently active tab (i.e. the one you are getting from `tabs.query()`).

Which is the better choice between injecting a script per functionality or one script which you message to initiate the desired function depends on your design and what you are attempting to do.  If they are functions that are relatively rare (in particular instigated by user action, as yours are), then injecting a script per function is often the better choice (it is something I do in one of my extensions). It is certainly better than having a rarely used script be injected on a large number of websites when the script is only there to start to do something when it [receives a message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) from the background script. For example, an extension that waits for user interaction with the Browser UI (not content UI) which then sends a message from the background script to the content script to perform a task. Definitely in that case, it is better to wait to inject the content script until it is needed.

Obviously, if the user interaction is going to start from within the webpage, not the browser UI, then the script needs to be injected on all relevant pages. When you do so you will need to use [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) between the content script and background script if the background script needs to do something which requires the wider access a background script has to the extension APIs.

### Describing content scripts injections in *manifest.json*

Without more information as to how you want your content scripts added to your *manifest.json* (e.g. scheme(s), domains, pages (i.e URLs), the script names, etc.) we can't tell you exactly how to do so, other than to [read the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). I will say that it would be unusual for you to be injecting the same content scripts using both your *manifest.json* and `tabs.executeScript()`. There is nothing inherently wrong with doing so. If it is the correct thing to do will depend on the code and site(s).

One of the things that might not have been clear from the documentation is that the `content_scripts` key is an Array of Objects. Each object describes one group of injections. All files in the object are injected into the pages that match the [URL patterns provided in that object](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#match-patterns-globs).  You can have as many objects describing groups of injections as you desire in the `content_scripts` array.

The following example both loads multiple content scripts and loads different content scripts onto different pages, using *manifest.json* (adapted from cod on [Chrome's Content Scripts page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)).

Into all pages matching `https://www.google.com/*`, it will inject *myGoogleStyles.css*, *jquery.js*, and *myGoogleScript.js*.
Into all pages matching `http://www.example.com/*`, it will inject *myExampleStyles.css*, *jquery.js*, and *myExampleScript.js*:

```json
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.google.com/*"],
      "css": ["myGoogleStyles.css"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "myGoogleScript.js"]
    },
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.example.com/*"],
      "css": ["myExampleStyles.css"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "myExampleScript.js"]
    }
  ],
```

Comment: Might want to mention [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) in your answer in the latter part.

Comment: @Xan, I added links to message passing, and a bit more text (including an example of injecting content scripts from *manifset.json*), although the OP really has not provided enough information to provide anything other than an example, which was basically covered in the docs. Expanding this has gotten me feeling that it is beginning to edge over into providing a tutorial rather than addressing the portions of the question which were specific enough for an answer.

Comment: I appreciate the jquery.js file in this example hahaha :)