# How can I edit a manifest.json file from a JS file?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I'm making a Google Chrome extension that parses a Twitter feed's source code when the user inputs the handle. I'm aware that you cannot extract an external site's source code unless you give it permission in the `manifest.json` file. However, the URL in my case will vary based on the Twitter handle that the user inputs, so how can I edit the manifest file directly from my `popup.js` script?

For example, I want something like this:

```
{
    "permissions": [
        "http://www.twitter.com/" + handle + "/with_replies"
    ]
}
```

in my `manifest.json` file and

```
var handle = "CNN";
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("http://www.twitter.com/" + handle + "/with_replies", function(data) {
        $("#body").text(data);
    });
});
```

to return the content of the Twitter feed for CNN.

************************************************ UPDATE ************************************************

So to test to see if my code works, I changed my `manifest.json` file to include `http://www.twitter.com/*` as a permission, and I changed my jQuery code to:

```
$.get("https://twitter.com/", function(data) {
    $("h5").text(data);
    });
});
```

This is inside an event listener that listens for a button click, so this should change the text of the h5 element to the source of the webpage, but it doesn't. I've tried replacing `https://www.twitter.com/*` with `https://www.twitter.com/` and it still doesn't work. But if I replace the jQuery code with something simple like `$("h5").text("Hello world!");`, it works fine. Is there something wrong with my jQuery code to extract the page's content?

This is what the permissions section in my manifest file looks like:

```
"permissions": [
 "activeTab",
 "storage",
 "https://twitter.com/*"
]
```

Comment: You can't, the manifest is processed by the browser.... even if you could change it, the changes probably would not take effect.

Comment: I think you could just put "`http://www.twitter.com`" on permissions.. or maybe "`http://www.twitter.com/*`"

Comment: @FelipeNathanCampigoto Thanks for the reply. I've tried your suggestions, but now there seems to be an issue with the execution of the jQuery, which I've updated above.

Comment: @FelipeNathanCampigoto Nevermind it works, it just took a little while to load :)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you could edit the file for security reasons.  However, it you could have multiple content_scripts executing on different occasions.  So if your condition is meet on that website, it will execute.

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["https://www.google.com/*"],
    "js": ["jquery.js", "myGoogleScript.js"]
  },
  {
    "matches": ["http://www.example.com/*"],
    "js": ["jquery.js", "myExampleScript.js"]
  }
]
```

For more go to: [Possible to have multiple content scripts for different functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40623095/possible-to-have-multiple-content-scripts-for-different-functions)